# Sonarqube wrong column type in public.users

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, sonarqube

I want to migrate from the embedded H2 database to a PostgreSQL database in SonarQube. I created the user and schema as [explained here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing). I also altered the search path.

The Sonar analysis is triggered as a post-build step in Jenkins, so I also adjusted the database configuration in Jenkins to use the PostgreSQL server.

The (maven) build finishes successfully but the sonar analysis now fails with:

```
[ERROR] Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Wrong column type in public.users 
        for column id. Found: int8, expected: int4
```

The full error stacktrace can be found here: http://pastebin.com/WBBQrS4u .

I'm using:

- SonarQube Server 4.1.2
- sonar-maven-plugin:2.2
- Jenkins: Sonar plugin 2.1
- Postgresql 9.3

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3 is not supported. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements. Could you check if you face the same issue with PostgreSQL 9.1? And try again with a fresh database on PostgreSQL 9.3? I'd like to narrow down the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @DavidRACODON-SonarSource Thank you for your advice, it was indeed a problem with PostgreSQL 9.3. I tried again, now with our MySQL 5.5 database and it works flawlessly. I'm sorry that I can't be of more help on the 9.3 vs. 9.1 issue but I assume it would've worked in 9.1. Many thanks!

Comment: The property sonar.jdbc.schema=public must be set on postgresq to avoid conflicts with table USERS.